# Java8: About Functional Interface

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I would like to ask about the following piece of code related to Functional Interfaces.
I am confused by:

```
Rideable rider = Car :: new
```

Is it creating a `Rideable` (interface) or `Car` (class) instance?
If it is creating a `Car` object, the constructor `new Car()` (i.e. with no arguments) should be not existing, then how come this can be valid?

I Have been reading through [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) ,but still could not figure it out.

```
@FunctionalInterface 
interface Rideable {
  Car getCar (String name);
}

class Car {
  private String name;

  public Car (String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rideable rider = Car :: new; 
    Car vehicle = rider.getCar("MyCar");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Lambda syntax to implement the `getCar()` method of the Rideable interface, where the following anonymous class program is omitted using Lambda's concise syntax:

```
Rideable rideable = new Rideable() {
    @Override
    public Car getCar(String name) {
        return new Car(name);
    }
};
```

This is Java 7 code. You can achieve the same thing using using Lambda expression:

```
Rideable rider = name -> new Car(name);
```

Or as in your example, using method reference:

```
Rideable rider = Car::new;
```

As a result, the `getCar(String)` method of the Rideable object can be used as a `new Car(String)`.

And as an answer to your question, you are creating an instance of `Car` class that implements the Rideable interface. This is another way you can implement an interface without using `implement` keyword.

If you are thinking of:

```
Car auto = Car("MyCar")::new;
```

or

```
Car auto = Car::new;
Car vehicle = auto::getCar("MyCar");
```

or

```
Car vehicle = Rideable::new::getCar("MyCar");
```

All these examples are `wrong` approaches. I gave you this examples because these are common mistakes that can be made when we are speaking about Lambda expressions or method reference.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it creating a Rideable (interface) or Car (class) instance?

It is creating an instance of (a class that implements) the `Rideable` interface.

The `Rideable` functional interface has a single method - `getCar` - that accepts a `String` argument and returns a `Car` instance.

The `public Car (String name)` constructor accepts a `String` argument and produces a `Car` instance.

Therefore the method reference `Car::new` (which in this case does not refer to a parameter-less constructor) can be used as implementation of the `Rideable` interface.

And if it helps to clarify the confusion, here's a lambda expression equivalent to the `Car::new` method reference:

```
Rideable rider = (String s) -> new Car(s);
```

or

```
Rideable rider = s -> new Car(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new object of "Car" which is "Rideable".
So yes, you are creating new "Car" object.

Now Rideable is defined as "expecting `nameOfTheCar` and gives you `Car` instance via `getCar()` method" and that is precisely what `"Car::new"` is doing.

```
Car::new
```

in this example is same as(as its assigned to Rideable)

```
carName -> new Car(carName)
```

Now the above behaviour is wrapped using lambda which would be Java7 look something like below:

```
Rideable rideable = new Rideable() {
    @Override
    public Car getCar(String carName ) {
        return new Car(carName);
    }
};
```

Now let's say you have another interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface SelfRideable {
    Car getSelfDriven();
}
```

And now if you do

```
SelfRideable selfDriven = Car::new;
```

Then it would not compile since now it does not have any parameter it its method(`getSelfDriven()`). For this to work, you would need to have default constructor.